# Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon login problems after installation of awesome wm

Tags: linux-mint, login, awesome

I am fairly new to Linux. I wanted to try a tiling window-manager and played around with i3. Then I decided to try `awesome-wm`. I installed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install awesome awesome-extra
```

After logging out of cinnamon, I changed the session to awesome-wm and wanted to log in but that failed with the message:

```
Your session only lasted less than 10 seconds ...
```

The `.xsession-errors` file says:

```
initctl: Verbindung zu Upstart nicht möglich: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
syndaemon: Kein Prozess gefunden
/etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
```

Now the same thing happens regardless of what session I like to start.
The only way I can start a cinnamon-session is with i.e. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> log in there and then

```
startx
```

**Edit**:

After the tip from Gilles my `.xsession-errors` shows:

```
initctl: Verbindung zu Upstart nicht möglich: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
syndaemon: Kein Prozess gefunden
+ PROGNAME=Xsession
+ OPTIONFILE=/etc/X11/Xsession.options
+ SYSRESOURCES=/etc/X11/Xresources
+ USRRESOURCES=/home/marc/.Xresources
+ SYSSESSIONDIR=/etc/X11/Xsession.d
+ USERXSESSION=/home/marc/.xsession
+ USERXSESSIONRC=/home/marc/.xsessionrc
+ ALTUSERXSESSION=/home/marc/.Xsession
+ echo /etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
/etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
+ test -f /etc/profile
+ . /etc/profile
+ [ $  ]
+ [  ]
+ id -u
+ [ 1000 -eq 0 ]
+ PS1=$ 
+ [ -d /etc/profile.d ]
+ [ -r /etc/profile.d/Z97-byobu.sh ]
+ . /etc/profile.d/Z97-byobu.sh
+ [ -r /usr/bin/byobu-launch ]
+ [ -r /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh ]
+ . /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
+ [ -n  -a -n $  -a -z  ]
+ [ -r /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh ]
+ . /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh
+ [ -n  -o -n  ]
+ return 0
+ unset i
+ test -f /home/marc/.profile
+ . /home/marc/.profile
+ [ -n  ]
+ [ -d /home/marc/bin ]
+ _byobu_sourced=1 . /usr/bin/byobu-launch
```

*Edit:*

After reading the `.xsession-errors` trace, I realized the lines about byobu, a program I also tried out and removed it again with:

```
sudo apt-get remove byobu
```

Obviously there are leftovers from that, so I reinstalled byobu and now the login works again! :)
I guess finding out about how to cleanly remove byobu is one of my next tasks.

Comment: To diagnose this, add the line `set -x` to the top of `/etc/mdm/Xsession` just after the top `#!` line. This causes every line in the script to be logged before it's executed. Then try logging in again and this time there should be a trace in `.xsession-errors` that hopefully leads to the cause of the problem.